# "use" php statement multiple?

Tags: php, symfony, silex

Is there any way to make a "multiple use"?

I'm using an plugin in Silex to use ORM with it, and in each Entity I have to make a use like this:

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Entity,
    Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Table,
    Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Id,
    Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Column,
    Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\GeneratedValue,
    Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ManyToOne,
    Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ManyToOne;
```

So, my question is, is there in PHP a "multiple using" like Java? I mean:

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\*;
```

Or maybe using an autoload technique made by Silex/Symfony or something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is not possible – by design.

Imagine, you have two "wildcard" uses, like this:

```
use Foo\*;
use Bar\*;
```

Now, somewhere in your code, you would be accessing a class of one of those namespaces, like this:

```
$a = new Something();
```

Now, the class `Something` probably needs to be autoloaded, but to do so, php would need to resolve the full namespace path of your class: `Foo\Something` or `Bar\Something`? Or did we mean the class `Something` inside the current namespace?

Comment: Easy: Java does not have this kind of autoloading feature.

Answer (score 5):

Why not do this...

`use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;`

Then in your annotations...

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="int")
 */
 protected $name;
```

And so on...

Comment: On Symfony it works, but not in Silex... it says something like "it's not a valid mapping entity"..

Comment: @user2111499 it should work everywhere, as it is a PHP feature. Can you show some code?

Comment: @user2111499 have you added `@ORM\Entity` to the annotations on the class?

Comment: I just try this solution, and I get the message: MappingException: Class "Entity\Car" is not a valid entity or mapped super class.

Comment: All of your entities need to have the `@ORM\Entity` annotation, including all entities that you reference in your annotations. If you post code it would help diagnose the problem

Comment: Okay, I use the Nutwerk service provider for ORM.

https://gist.github.com/anonymous/5039479

In the gist shows the ORM service provider configuration, and the Car.php annotation.